# What does the computation of irrationality and transcendentality via a fancy implementation of analytic Markov's property look like?

Tags: lo.logic, computer-science, constructive-mathematics, realizability

Proofs that various real numbers are not rational or not algebraic tend to be constructively valid as is. Examples include the proofs that $\sqrt 2$ and $\log_2(3)$ are not rational and that $e$ is not algebraic.

However, constructively we have better notions. A real number $r$ is [*irrational*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/irrational+number#in_the_real_numbers) when $\forall q \in \mathbb Q. r < q \lor r > q$. A real number $r$ is transcendental when $\forall p \in \mathbb Z[x]. p \neq 0 \implies (p(r) < 0 \lor p(r) > 0)$. The three examples above also satisfy these definitions, but the original proofs no longer work.

Unless we add an axiom known as [*analytic Markov's principle*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/analytic+Markov%27s+principle), which is equivalent to $$\forall x, y \in \mathbb R. x ≠ y \implies (x < y \lor y < x)$$

This axiom is computable. Here is the boring way to compute it. Given $x$ and $y$, start producing rational approximations to $x - y$. Since this is nonzero, the approximations don't converge to 0, so you'll eventually be able to determine the sign.

However, [there are more interesting ways to compute Markov's principle](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/972/incorporating-markovs-principle-in-various-proof-assistants#976) (such as "static exceptions") that actually analyze the proof of $x ≠ y$.

First, here's a slightly stronger version of Markov's principle that implies analytic Markov's principle.

> **Slightly stronger Markov's principle for formulas $\phi$ and $\psi(n)$** 
> Given $\forall n \in \mathbb N. (\phi \lor \psi(n))$ and $\lnot \forall n \in \mathbb N. \psi(n)$ conclude $\phi$

(You recover the original Markov's principle by setting $\phi$ as $\exists n. \lnot \psi(n)$.)

We derive analytic Markov's property by setting $\phi$ as $x \in (-\infty, y) \cup (y, \infty)$ and $\psi(n)$ as $x \in (y - \frac 1 {2^n}, y + \frac 1 {2^n})$. If $\forall n. x \in (y - \frac 1 {2^n}, y + \frac 1 {2^n})$, then $x$ and $y$ have the same Dedekind cut, contradicting $x ≠ y$.

Here is an interesting way to give it computational content (what I think Pédrot is calling static exceptions.) Create a "fake term" proving $\forall n \in \mathbb N. \psi(n)$ that tries to generate a term for $\psi(n)$ using the first hypothesis but if it returns a term for $\phi$ instead then an error is thrown. Now try to derive $\bot$ using this term and the second hypothesis. Since deriving $\bot$ is impossible, this must run into an error. This error contains a term for $\phi$. (The reason we restrict to $\mathbb N$ is because it is too simple to smuggle out the fake term. If we used a more complicated type, the fake term could end up in the proof term for $\phi$ somehow.)

Given all of these layers of abstraction, it's hard to see what is happening. For example, consider the proof of $\sqrt 2 ≠ \frac ab$ based on the integer inequality $2 b^2 ≠ a^2$. **What is actually happening** when we convert this to a proof of $\sqrt 2 < \frac ab \lor \frac ab < \sqrt 2$? For example, how efficient is it, and which $n$ triggers the error?

Comment: As you yourself point out, the program will simply take $a/b$ as input, compute $\sqrt{2}$ with sufficient precision until it can be separated from $a/b$ (which will happen eventually as it is proved that they cannot be equal) and return the sign of the difference: Markov's principle is just a way of stating that we are accepting such a construction. Pédrot's answer is just about various ways of *presenting* it in proof assistants (e.g., vis-à-vis typing), but it is still just the same. I don't know what mode you expect as an answer.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen the implementation I gave of MP is far more efficient on some tasks. For example, consider the decidable formula $\phi(n)$ defined as "n = 10^100". Let the proof of $\lnot \forall n. n ≠ 10^{100}$ be given by universal instantiation on $10^{100}$. Then brute force MP takes $10^{100}$ steps but fancy MP only takes $\log_2(10^{100})$ steps to normalize the term (or even only 1 step if optimized further). In addition, in general brute force MP always returns the minimal possible $n$, but fancy MP might not.